Type of user input C++
Hi i want to make my code find out variable type of user input in C++
like:
int x; 

cout<<"enter a vaild number: ";

cin>>x; 

if(what i should say here to check if the variable was integer or not){cout<<"correct";} 

else{cout<<" x is not vaild number";} 

i tried somethings like putting check integer
like:
int x,check; 

cin>>x;

if(x=check){cout<<"good";}

else{cout<<"bad";} 

but the computer will always print the good syntax although the x wasn't integer

x = check assigns the value of check to the variable x ... investigate c++ comparison operators

Read the whole line as a string, then use e.g. std::stoi to try and convert the input to an integer with validation.

if the variable was integer or not  ... the or not is redundant

You have gone wrong already. If you want to check that the input is in the form of an integer you have to read something that will not fail if the input is not in the form of an integer. So read the input as a string, then check if the string can legally be converted to an integer. Depending on that, then either convert the string to an integer, or take whatever action you want to take on bad input.

There's nothing you can do with x to tell if it was given a valid number or not. You have to ask the stream if the last operation was successful.
int x; 
cout<<"enter a valid number: ";
cin>>x; 
if (cin.good()) {cout<<"correct";} 
else {cout<<" x is not vaild number"; cin.clear();}  

clear() tells the stream that the error is handled, so the next cin operation will try to read what the user typed.
And, since this is supposed to be common, istream::operator bool() does this check. So this can simply be:
int x;
cout<<"enter a valid number: ";
if (cin>>x) {
    cout<<"correct";
} else {
    cout<<" x is not vaild number"; 
    cin.clear();
}  


If you want to do more specific value checking, then the usual way to do that is to make a type that only checks for specific inputs, and sets the fail bit.
struct yes_no {
    bool value;

    true_false& operator=(bool value_) {value=value_; return *this;}
    operator bool() const {return value;}
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, yes_no& value) {
    value = false; //always initialize the value before reading
    std::string buffer;
    if (!(in >> buffer)) return in;
    if (buffer == "yes") {
        value = true;
    } else if (buffer == "no") {
        value = false;
    } else {
        in.setstate(in.rdstate()|std::ios_base::failbit);
    }
    return in;
}


@mooting duck this don't help, cin.fail() check out of user variable type like... i asked him to write yes or no and he wrote nope, the cin.fail() will see that user input is true bc its a string,and this what i don't want to happen

@محمدادم The question appears to be about validating if the user inputed an int relative to "not an int", which this correctly does. If you wanted to check yes and no vs nope, then the question needs clarification.
